# $scope variable not updating when factory object changes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using `angular-chart.js` to draw a chart on my view. It gets the data from mongodb. I have a factory set up to use the API to get the data, but once the data is updated the chart is not updating, even though the scope variables are binded to the factory service object.

chartFactory.js

```js
app.factory('chartFactory', ['$http', '$interval', function($http, $interval) {
  var service = {}
  service.chartData = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
  ]

  getData()

  function getData() {
    $http.get('/portfolio/get-chart-data')
      .then(function(response) {
        service.chartData = response.data
        console.log(response.data, 'response data') //response.data is an array
      })
  }

  return service
}])
```

And this is where I am defining the scope variables, which is the data teh chart is drawn from. According to the docs, the chart should update when the scope variables update. Maybe I am not binding correctly?

chartController.js

```js
app.controller('chartCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http, chartFactory) {

      $scope.height_chart = window.innerHeight * 0.4
      $scope.labels = chartFactory.chartData[0];
      $scope.series = chartFactory.chartData['GDAX Value'];
      $scope.data = [ chartFactory.chartData[1] ];
      $scope.onClick = function(points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
      };
      $scope.datasetOverride = [{
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
      }];

      $scope.options = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            //    type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                  return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                } else {
                  return '$' + value;
                }
              }
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            display: false
          }]
        }
      }
})
```

How to have the chart update when factory updates the service object?

Answer (score 0):

You're already exposing `chartData` through your factory so now you can add a `$scope.chartData` variable to your controller that references the factory's `chartData` array directly.

```
$scope.chartData = chartFactory.chartData;
```

Now you have a variable in your controller's `$scope` that references the `chartData`, so any changes in one will be reflected in the other, both variables are now referencing the same array (object).

I wasn't sure if you would have to re-render the chart, but having a quick read of the docs for [Angular Chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) it does say that it updates automatically so you should be fine.

> All charts are reactive and will update automatically when data
>   changes."